# How to accept user data and return as a graph after submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, database, web

I want to build a simple web app that asks the user to enter a number from a scale of 1 to 100. After the user enters a number and hits submit, a bar graph showing the distribution of responses appears.

My question: what technology would you use to accept the responses and be able to retrieve the data?

EDIT: There's gotta be a better way to store information from a user than a SQL database, right? All I'm hoping to store are numbers from 1 to 100. I'm not asking about rendering a graph FYI. I'm looking for the most lightweight alternative to my problem.

Comment: yeah not helpful. I know how to use Google Charts. I'm asking how you collect the information and store it to retrieve it later? I'm crowd sourcing user input, not trying to render a chart.

Comment: @FrankBi Use a database to store information.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid deploying an SQL database just for storing numbers. Maybe I should have framed the question to what alternatives are there to storing data on the web. Something more lightweight.

Comment: @FrankBi In retrospect, my comment seems quite aggressive. I just meant to get some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what kind of data you are collecting, if it's just numbers, even a comma separated value list could do the job of storing it. But there are other options, like `serialize()` or `json_encode()`. Of course, there are database out there, but for a list of 100 numbers (as I read your question you want to store how many users chose what number, with the chosen number as the array index and the number of people as the value, a simple array does the job). You can store the output of both `serialize()` and `json_encode()` in a file.

[`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) in the PHP Manual;
[`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/serialize) in the PHP manual.

To reverse the encoding, use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) or [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/unserialize).

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. Hard to come by here sometimes.